# I can't add a body field?

Tags: craft3

I have made a new "section" called Blog. In the dashboard I now have a quick post panel but I can only input a title and nothing else? How can I add the ability to have a body etc?

Comment: You've tagged this question `craft3`, but it's unclear that you're actually using Craft 3 (which is still in [developer preview](https://craftcms.com/3)). Judging by the level of this question, either (A) you've mistakenly tagged this with the wrong version of Craft, or (B) you've mistakenly started using Craft 3 (which is unstable) instead of the standard [Craft 2](https://craftcms.com/). Can you be certain that you are, in fact, using Craft 3?

Comment: On a second read-through, I noticed your question is specifically about the "Quick Post" dashboard widget. If you want to use the full entry editor, try clicking "Entries" in the _Main Menu_, and looking for your _Blog_ Section. It's possible to configure which fields appear in the Quick Post widget, when it's created. Try clicking the gear in the upper-right corner of the widget to select which fields are visible.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've probably gone through the process of creating a new *Section*, but have not assigned any fields to it.

In Craft, the differences between each of your *Sections* and *Entry Types* comes in the various fields you assign to them.

I suggest you take a look at the intro to [Sections and Entries](https://craftcms.com/docs/sections-and-entries), then at [Fields](https://craftcms.com/docs/fields).

The typical content structure definition process looks something like:

1. Create a *Section* and at least one *Entry Type*
2. Create a *Field Group*
3. Add *Fields* to the *Field Group*
4. Add the Field Group or individual *Fields* to your *Entry Type(s)*
5. Add or Edit your content by creating or modifying an *Entry*.

In your case, you've probably done step 1 and step 5. Try adding some fields (like "Body" or "Tags") and assigning them to your Entry Type.

Comment: Still cant see a body field? Do you mind going into a but more detail? I have checked out the link but I'm even more lost... @August Miller

Comment: @JackSewell You're probably looking for the `Rich Text` field type. You use whatever _Name_ and _Handle_ you want, but there isn't any primary content field, by default.